# Show buttons in bot framework emulator with sourceEvent

Tags: botframework

I don't want to use `builder.Prompts.choice`since i want to allow user type answer not only click buttons. So i use sourceEvent, works great with facebook messenger but know i don't have ability to test my bot in emulator, since buttons not appear.

```
replyMessage.sourceEvent({
    facebook: {
        quick_replies: [
            {
                "content_type": "text",
                "title": "Money Management",
                "payload": "Money Management"
            },
            {
                "content_type": "text",
                "title": "Retirement Plans",
                "payload": "Retirement Plans"
            }
        ]
    },
});
```

How to show buttons with sourceEvent in emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Ok screenshot we see that buttons get to bot emulator as attachments.

```
let replyMessage = new builder.Message(session).text("hi");
replyMessage.addAttachment(
            {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                "content": {
                    "buttons": [ {"type": "postBack", "title": "Your title", "value": "your value"} ]
                }
            }
        );
```